# How to get nonce for braintree payment gateway in flutter?

Tags: flutter, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm using BrainTree payment gateway in my flutter app and using this library https://pub.dev/packages/braintree_payment for payment.

So the code is also given on that page like this :

```
String clientNonce = " GET YOUR CLIENT NONCE FROM YOUR SERVER";

BraintreePayment braintreePayment = new BraintreePayment();
var data = await braintreePayment.showDropIn(
        nonce: clientNonce, amount: "2.0", enableGooglePay: true);
```

But i don't know how to get **clientNonce** or **Nonce** from server,
So can anyone suggest how to get the nonce that we need to pass in order to show the drop in UI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Use an HTTP library to fetch the data from an endpoint on your server.

For example, this one: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

When your server endpoint receives this request, it must obtain a new nonce and return it.

Comment: I'm not able to find any API like that to call API

Comment: Effectively you are building your own API between your client and your server. The only required parameter is that you return the nonce from the server to the client.

Comment: But see the above library's documentation and see there what they are saying

Comment: This is not what you're suggesting

Comment: It is exactly what I am suggesting, and what you need to do. The above is a general-purpose HTTP package for flutter, which I have never tried. Use a different one if you prefer.

Comment: Which package you're suggesting?

Comment: See my answer for the suggestion, and use a different one if you prefer.